# Do vectors $(\sin n x)_{n=1}^d$ always form a basis of ${\mathbb R}^d$ for $d$ distinct $x \in (0, \pi )$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Points on the moment curve $(y,y^2,\ldots, y^d)$ always form a basis of ${\mathbb R}^d$ for $d$ different non-zero choices of $y$. The determinant formula for a Vandermonde matrix says that this is even true for complex-valued $y$ and ${\mathbb C}^d$. So we could use $y = e^{ix}$ for different real $x \in (0,\pi)$ and get a basis for ${\mathbb C}^d$. This seems to suggest that the real and imaginary components should form bases of ${\mathbb R}^d$ and $i{\mathbb R}^d$ respectively as vector spaces over ${\mathbb R}$. Hence the question, do vectors $(\sin x, \sin 2x, \ldots, \sin dx)$ always form a basis of ${\mathbb R}^d$ for $d$ distinct values $x \in (0,  \pi )$ ? If so, what's an easy way to see it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your $\Bbb R^d$ is supposed to be the vector space $V$ which is simply the linear span of $(\sin n x)_{n=1}^d$. By definition $(\sin n x)_{n=1}^d$ is a generating set of $V$ and we only have to show that these functions are linearly indepent.

To do this, consider the scalar product $$(f,g)=\int_0^{2\pi} fg dx$$ on $V$. It is easy to show that $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(nx)\sin(mx) dx=0$ for $n\neq m$. Therefore, the vectors $(\sin n x)_{n=1}^d$ are mutually orthogonal and hence linearly independent.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. The OP is not talking about a space of functions.

Comment: Indeed, this is not a space of functions. This is a set of $d$-dimensional vectors where the $n$th entry is $\sin nx$ for a value $x \in (0, \pi)$.